# Get value with different name and same id in select option

Tags: html, html-select

Please help me in this situation i have uploaded the code through image your can see the code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Selector IDs should be unique while your IDs are identical "wakeupdaily". There are a number of ways to read select tag values, but the simplest dependency free solution would be to use native JS.

```js
function select1() {
    var res = document.getElementById("wakeupdaily1").value;
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = res;
}

function select2() {
    var res = document.getElementById("wakeupdaily2").value;
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<select name ="daily1item1[]" id="wakeupdaily1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button onclick="select1()">Get Value</button>
<p id="result1"></p>


<select name ="daily1item2[]" id="wakeupdaily2">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button onclick="select2()">Get Value</button>
<p id="result2"></p>
```